# In crontab is it possible to specify a user from a variable?

Tags: users, cron

I am trying to have the following cron executed with a certain user.

```
U=`/usr/bin/w | grep -w :0 | awk '{ print $1 }'`
*/1 * * * * $U /opt/script.sh
```

It seems the deamon doesn't know how to interpret this command; I get :

> /usr/sbin/cron[18698]: (CRON) bad username (/etc/cron.d/script)

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 6):

No, a crontab file is not a shell script you can't just introduce arbitrary commands or variables. If you want to do this, run the script as root and change users in the script.

To determine sessions have a look at `consolekit` which you can use to get all active sessions on your system either via `dbus` or `ck-list-sessions`

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer.
To have this working I used `crontab /opt/cronjob` in the bash_profile